# Salesforce API UpsertResult scheme

Tags: salesforce, upsert

Is there any way to customise the fields that are returned after a successful Salesforce Upsert call?

I was hoping it would just be a case of changing the definition of the UpsetResult within my enterprise WSDL, but that didn't work.

I want to reduce the number of API calls I make by returning the OwnerId of the upserted object along with the standard fields, but I can't find anywhere within Salesforce where I can change what is returned.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't change what's returned by the standard upsert call. One option would be to write an [apex web service](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_web_services_methods.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_web_services_methods.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) that does upsert followed by query in apex and have it return the data you want that way. The call to your apex web service would only count as 1 api call, reducing the number of calls you're making.